# Python Extracting a substring of variable length

Tags: python, regex, substring, extract, slice

I'm trying to extra the name of a module from some verilog code. For example:

```
module uart (inputs, outputs, etc)
```

I know I can use pythons slicing to get a substring, but that only uses indexes. I need to make it so that it slices kind of like this: string[6: (], where it slices up until the first instance of a parentheses. I was thinking of using string.find to find the index first parentheses and substituting that into the slice, but I'm curious if there's a better way to do this, maybe using regular expressions or something?

Comment: an example will be helpful

Comment: Example of the verilog code or the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using regex. Starts capturing after the 6th character and up to the first instance of an opening parens:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "abcdefghijklmno(adfa adfds("
>>> m = re.search(r'.{6}(.*?)\(', string)
>>> m.group(1)
'ghijklmno'
```

This regex will capture up to the first newline or opening parens, whichever it sees first. The ?: portion means it is a non-capturing group. We don't need to store that data... we're just using the group for the or ('|') operation:

```
r'.{6}(.*?)(?:\(|\n)'
```

Comment: If I want to also check up until a newline, would I just add |\n at the end of the regex? Would a multiline specification be necessary? Thanks.

Comment: My regex pasted into the comments broke, so I updated my answer for you.